# Reshaping arrays using Numpy.Reshape

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to reshape an array using numpy.reshape but always come across the index error

```
"IndexError: index 15484 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 7231"
```

I then printed out the shape of the array which was

```
(7231,80,60,4)
```

My code is

```
X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,80,60,1)
```

(im trying to reshape all of my image to (-1,80,60,1))

I thought -1 autocompleted the dimensions, so i am confused as to why I am getting this error?

train is:

```
    train = train_data[:-500]
```

and train_data is an array with tuples of image pixels and labels

Can someone help me?

Comment: What is the actual code that create the issue? Isn't it `[i[0] for i in train]`?

Comment: Probably, since it is an index error, but how do I fix it?

Comment: Well, we don't know what `train` is, so no idea.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I added the context

Comment: You don't show the code that is indexing with 15484.

Comment: While your question and comments are confusing, it appears that you want to change an array with final dimensions of `..,60,4` to one with `...,1`.  The only thing that reshape can do is change it to `...,240,1`.  It can only group adjacent dimensions.

Comment: @hpaulj wait a sec. If that's true, then what the heck is the code in my answer doing? Reshaping a `(7231,80,60,4)` array with `arr.reshape(-1,80,60,1)` appears to correctly create an array of shape `(28924, 80, 60, 1)`. I assume I'm missing something.

Comment: Try that reshaping on a small array where you can see a pattern in the numbers.  That reshaping 'works', but it jumbles the values.  I suspect you want `np.vstack([X[...,i] for i in range(4)]), that is joining `X[...,0], X[...,1]`, etc on the first axis.  That's not a simple reshape;

Answer (score 2):

Be careful when reshaping.  Even if it works, the arrangement of elements may not be what you want.

Start with a simple array that we can visualize:

```
In [805]: x = np.arange(24).reshape(3,2,4)
In [806]: x
Out[806]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7]],

       [[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15]],

       [[16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
```

reshape to (-1,2,1) - but lets drop the last 1 for a more compact display:

```
In [807]: x.reshape(-1,2)
Out[807]: 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 8,  9],
       [10, 11],
       [12, 13],
       [14, 15],
       [16, 17],
       [18, 19],
       [20, 21],
       [22, 23]])
```

Notice how the original [0,1,2,3] line gets split into 2 lines.

Another way of redistributing the last dimension of size 4 is:

```
In [808]: np.vstack([x[...,i] for i in range(4)])
Out[808]: 
array([[ 0,  4],
       [ 8, 12],
       [16, 20],
       [ 1,  5],
       [ 9, 13],
       [17, 21],
       [ 2,  6],
       [10, 14],
       [18, 22],
       [ 3,  7],
       [11, 15],
       [19, 23]])
```

That may be clearer if we used `np.stack` and got (4,3,2) shape

```
array([[[ 0,  4],
        [ 8, 12],
        [16, 20]],
  ....
```

`x.transpose(2,0,1)` produces the same thing.

`reshape` preserves the ravelled/flattened order of elements.  Transpose changes it.

```
In [812]: x.transpose(2,0,1).ravel()
Out[812]: 
array([ 0,  4,  8, 12, 16, 20,  1,  5,  9, 13, 17, 21,  2,  6, 10, 14,...])
In [813]: x.reshape(-2,2).ravel()
Out[813]: 
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, ...])
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have doesn't do what you think it does. `i[0]` gets the 0th element in the first axis, which is your `80`, that's not what you want.

Anyway, what you really what is just to select the first slice in the fastest direction, so just do:

```
X = train[:,:,:,0:1]
```

If your data is not actually the size you say it is, then try:

```
X = np.array([i.reshape(80, 60, 4)[:,:,0:1] for i in train])
```

Comment: when I do this:  X = np.array(train[:,:,:,0:1]).reshape(-1,80,60,1),  it gives me this error:     X = np.array(train[:,:,:,0:1]).reshape(-1,80,60,1)
IndexError: too many indices for array

Comment: But why do you want to create a new array and reshape it?? And if `train` has the shape you say it has, then just use `train[:,:,:,0:1]`.

Comment: From the OP's description, I'm pretty sure that `train`/`train_data` is really a 1D array of dtype `O` that contains tuples of `(3D array, str)`. I don't think your 4D slice will work for them. Rather, their current list comprehension `np.array([i[0] for i in train])` is probably what they actually want.

Comment: The OP very not specifically said that `the array` had that shape. You know, that's on them. At this point I wouldn't make too many strong assumption (or weak ones, for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

Reshaping an array of shape `(7231,80,60,4)` -> `(-1,80,60,1)` does "just work":

```
train = np.arange(np.prod((7231,80,60,4))).reshape(7231,80,60,4)
print(train.shape)

X = train.reshape(-1,80,60,1)
print(X.shape)
```

Output:

```
(7231, 80, 60, 4)
(28924, 80, 60, 1)
```

So the issues you're having must not directly stem from the reshape that you're trying to do. My guess is that your problem might relate to the form/contents of your `train_data` array (or the array you try to create from it with `np.array([i[0] for i in train])`). Of course, the problem could also be in a section of your code that you didn't post in your question. It would probably be helpful if you posted a bit more of your actual code.

In particular, when you got the error message:

```
IndexError: index 15484 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 7231
```

it should have included a stack trace that pointed directly back to the problematic line in your code. Did the stack trace say that the error was raised from the line in which you create `X`:

```
X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,80,60,1)
```

or did it point to a different line in your code?